# Compressing an array of integers in C using zlib

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I need an urgent help about compressing an array of integers using zlib,and that will be in c language.
i have:    **uint16_t arrayOfData[120]**  and i want to compress it so that i get the compressed version and use it in the same program (i don't want to read from and write to streams). 
please i am waiting for any help, if sample code is available it will be great!

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: To those who want to cast a close-vote: please rethink. This question seems valid and on-topic. It lacks research, that's sure. But it's not offtopic, and the author is quite clear about what's needed. IMHO, it deserves a '-1', not closing.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example at http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html .

Comment: The code below is my trial for compression.Actually i want to compress an array of INTEGERS,not CHARS as in the code.I found that the compress and uncompress methods require parameters of type UNSIGNED CHAR * for the buffer (input and output), My question is HOW CAN I ADAPT THE CODE TO DEAL WITH INTEGERS (INPUT BUFFER AND OUTPUT)?.should change the zlib parameters or only casting from int to char(i tried casting but with errors)

Comment: Casting works fine.  All data, including an array of integers, can be treated as a sequence of bytes.  Just make sure that you correctly calculate the number of bytes in the array. If you are compressing and decompressing on the same machine, you will have no problem.  If you want to transport the compressed data between machines, then you need to pay attention to the length and ordering of the bytes in your integers.  To be portable, you will need to encode the integers as bytes by using shift operations, and then reverse the operation on the other end.

Comment: Thank you for the help.Actually i need to transfer the compressed buffer(compressed integer audio samples)as a block to another PC where i plan to decompress it and get it back as an array of integers(samples),and then playback the samples. I hope that casting doesn't make problems for such application.

Comment: As I said, if you are going between machines you need to disassemble the integers to sequences of bytes, and reassemble them at the other end.  Just casting on both ends may very well cause it to fail, due to integers being different sizes or ordered differently on the two machines (least significant byte first vs. most significant byte first).

Comment: Thanks, i will be careful at this.I would like to ask about the compression ratio, i tried compressing a buffer of 150 uint8_t but i got 114 elements in the compressed buffer (150:114), isn't it a low compression ratio?

Comment: You can't expect much out of such a short sample.  You need to give the compressor much more to work with in order to find possibly repeated strings or skewed statistics.  That's what it needs to compress.